# $watchCollection on an array of js objects in an Angular Controller requires an anonymous function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I have a simple js array being retrieved by an angular factory, injected into a control, watched, then displayed in a table using ng-repeat from within a view state managed by ui-router.

Initially I attempted to subscribe to this array using $watchCollection...

```
self.$watchCollection( self.Data, function(newData, oldData){
  self.total = newData.length;
});
```

However this was only running when I initially load the app. I found that the only way to subscribe to the running collection was to use an anonymous function returning the array in question.

```
self.$watchCollection( function() { return self.Data }, function(newData, oldData){
  self.totalWatchedWithAnonFunc = newData.length;
})
```

View this all in http://plnkr.co/edit/L7mycl

From everything I read, all I should have needed to do for a valid subscription was to pass in the array itself and not an anonymous function that returns the array.

The reason I included ui-router is because my actual application is using it heavily and I wanted to mock up my environment as closely as possible to how I've got things set up.

What am I not understanding? Could I be doing something differently?

Thanks.

Comment: Updated per stevuu's suggestion :: http://plnkr.co/edit/L7mycl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `self.$watchCollection("Data", ...)` instead of `self.$watchCollection(self.Data, ...)`? Try it out! See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) to see why: the first argument is a string evaluated on the scope, or a function taking a scope that returns something you want to watch.

Comment: The property name as a string?!?! I am stunned that this is the solution...and not even scoped? That's some crazy new territory...thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: It's a recurring thing in AngularJS to evaluate strings on the scope, things like `ngRepeat`, `ngInit`, `ngInclude`, et cetera et cetera, all take expressions that are evaluated on the current scope. It's a little *odd* compared to other languages/frameworks but when you get used to it, it's quite powerful!